SCP- Permission denied error
I found out that this issue is very recurrent, and many people have already asked it before. But the fixes suggested are not working for me.
I am trying to copy file from my local machine to server to which I have access.
scp -r /path/data/ server:/home/USERNAME/
and this is the error I am getting.
server: Permission denied (publickey). scp: Connection closed

What makes you think you "have access"? How do you connect to prove it to yourself? With what exact command?

It seems clear that you don't have access to the server system, at least not using public key authentication. What fixes have you tried and in what exact ways have these not worked?

What's the username on the remote server, or more importantly is it (exactly) the same as your username on your local client?

The Permission denied (publickey) error message indicates the server is configured to accept SSH key authentication only.
If you think you should already have the authentication keys configured, read the logs at the server side: less /var/log/secure, less /var/log/auth.log or journalctl -u sshd.service, depending on distribution, to find out the exact reason the server is rejecting your key.
A common reason is that the permissions of the authorized_keys file or the directory it's in allow the file to be modified by someone other than the owner of the user account or root.
On the remote server, you can use namei -l $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys to see all the relevant permissions and ownerships at once: the permissions of the file itself, and of all the (grand)parent directories, all the way to the root directory. If any of those are group- or world-writeable, sshd will reject the authorized_keys file because users other than the account owner may have had a chance to modify it.
Ideally, the result of the namei -l command should look similar to this:
f: /home/dpatel/.ssh/authorized_keys
drwxr-xr-x root     root     /
drwxr-xr-x root     root     home
drwxr-xr-x dpatel   dpatel   dpatel
drwx------ dpatel   dpatel   .ssh
-rw------- dpatel   dpatel   authorized_keys

